# UIScrollView not hiding content

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView with a rectangular frame to display a set of subViews and page them, I would expect those other subViews to be hidden and only the current content displayed but instead I get all this overlap onto my screen.

[image]

```
if scrollViewHasBeenSetUp == false {
            var index = 0
            for event in eventList.events {
                let match = getMatchCell(event)
                match.frame = CGRect(x: index * Int(matchScrollView.frame.width), y: 0, width: Int(matchScrollView.frame.width), height: Int(matchScrollView.frame.height))
                matchScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: Int(match.frame.width) * eventList.events.count, height: 120)
                matchScrollView.addSubview(match)
                index++
                print("cell frame: \(match.frame)")
            }
            scrollViewHasBeenSetUp = true
        }
```

Using the visual inspector you can see the scrollViews frame has been set correctly but its content still isn't being hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you select clip subviews?

[image]

And I see your y is always 0,is it a vertical scroll view?

Comment: Thanks, I would have thought this might be a default setting!